# What is the different between "binding" and "binding context" in xamarin forms?

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin. I want to know the exact differences between binding and binding context which are used to bind data in xamarin forms.

Answer (score 5):

`Binding` and `BindingObject` are part of the data-binding process that comes with Xamarin Forms framework.

Data binding is the process that establishes a connection between a target (usually a control property like `Switch`.`IsToggled`) and a source (usually a viewmodel that incorporates business logic along with property change notifications).

[image]

You use `Binding` to define the connection between the target UI control and it's corresponding view model as source, which is provided through the `BindingContext` property. You do this by specifying the `Path` property (and other parameters such as Converter, StringFormat etc.).

For example, in this case as referred in above image, you can define a `Binding` to establish a connection between `Entry.Text` and `ViewModel.MyProperty` using `BindingContext` as source (which in turn is the `ViewModel`).

`BindingContext` is always considered the default source for such a binding, unless you explicitly specify an alternate source like another control, static resource etc.

For example:

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
```

will establish a binding connection between `Switch`.`IsToggled` and `BindingContext`.`IsEnabled`.

Similarly,

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsEnabled, Source={x:Reference siblingControl}}" />
```

will establish a binding connection between `Switch`.`IsToggled` and `siblingControl`.`IsEnabled`. You will notice, `BindingContext` is not part of this binding connection.

This [article](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-binding/) is a great starting point to learn binding in Xamarin forms. Another good resource is the official documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/), and [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/). Also, would recommend you read about how to [define bindings using markup-extensions in XAML](https://xamarinhelp.com/xaml-markup-extension-cheatsheet/) or [extension methods in C#](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObjectExtensions.SetBinding/p/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/System.String/).